# Find duplicate items in list based on particular member value

Tags: c#, linq

How can I find duplicate items in list based on particular value and group the duplicated items together?

If I have items that have same email address, I want them to be collected as duplicates because I use email address as "primary key" in the collection. Not all values are same in these items.

For example:

```
var numberOfTestcasesWithDuplicates = 
                                 Customers.GroupBy(x => x.emailaddress).ToList();
```

Would give me a collection of duplicated items, but then I want to collect the duplicated items into grouped collections where I can managed these items and see what items are duplicated?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want only the groups that have more than one item?

```
var numberOfTestcasesWithDuplicates = Customers.GroupBy(x => x.emailaddress)
                                               .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                                               .ToList();
```

The `.Where(p => p.Count() > 1)` will check how many items compose the group.

Comment: Yes exactly I just wanted the duplicated items into grouped. This works perfectly for me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find duplicate items in list based on particular value and group the duplicated items together?

Sounds like `GroupBy` to me. You've already *done* that grouping in the code in the question - you just need to use the results. The result of `GroupBy` is a *sequence of groups* where each group is a key and a sequence of values sharing that key. For example:

```
foreach (var group in Customers.GroupBy(x => x.emailaddress))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customers with email address {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var customer in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", customer.Name); // Or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yuck: Nope. `group` isn't a keyword. It's a contextual keyword.

Comment: I don't want to write out to the screen every item in the list and also duplicated items... duplicated times to the screen?